# Como faço para percorrer a seguinte array utilizando javaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

json

```
[  
   {  
      "idDisciplina":"1",
      "0":"1",
      "Nome":"Matematica",
      "1":"Matematica"
   },
   {  
      "idDisciplina":"11",
      "0":"11",
      "Nome":"Ciencia",
      "1":"Ciencia"
   }
]
```

script

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "includes/disciplina.php/",
     type: "POST",
     data: {
         id: id
     },
     success: function(json) {
         $("#idDiciplina").html("");
         console.log(json);

         $('#idDiciplina').append("<option value='' selected='selected'>Disciplinas</option>");

         for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
             $('#idDiciplina').append("<option value=" + json[0][i] + ">" + json[1][i] + "</option>");

         }

     }

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

A maneira mais semântica é usando o `.reduce()`. Assim percorres essa array e vais juntando conteúdo a uma string de HTML e no fim só precisas de tocar no DOM 1 vez, diretamente com o `.html()` para apagar conteúdo anterior e inserir o novo todo de uma vez só.

```js
var json = [{ "idDisciplina": "1", "0": "1", "Nome": "Matematica", "1": "Matematica" }, { "idDisciplina": "11", "0": "11", "Nome": "Ciencia", "1": "Ciencia" }, { "idDisciplina": "12", "0": "12", "Nome": "Geologia", "1": "Geologia" }];

var html = json.reduce(function(string, obj) {
  return string + "<option value=" + obj.idDisciplina + ">" + obj.Nome + "</option>"
}, "<option value='' selected='selected'>Disciplinas</option>");

$("#idDiciplina").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="idDiciplina"></select>

var json = [{
  "idDisciplina": "1",
  "0": "1",
  "Nome": "Matematica",
  "1": "Matematica"
}, {
  "idDisciplina": "11",
  "0": "11",
  "Nome": "Ciencia",
  "1": "Ciencia"
}, {
  "idDisciplina": "12",
  "0": "12",
  "Nome": "Geologia",
  "1": "Geologia"
}];
```

Comment: Mt bom, com o  reduce é melhor mesmo. [reduce()](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/javascript/map-filter-reduce-javascript/)

Comment: Dá esse erro aqui ó:
Uncaught TypeError: json.reduce is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer:

```
for (i=0 ; i<json.json.length ; i++){
     var idDisciplica = json.json[i].idDisciplina;
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.success (cadastroQuestao.php:134)
    at b (jquery.js:109)
    at XMLHttpRequest.x.onreadystatechange (jquery.js:114)
success @ cadastroQuestao.php:134
b @ jquery.js:109
x.onreadystatechange @ jquery.js:114
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
ajax @ jquery.js:115
run @ cadastroQuestao.php:120
onchange @ cadastroQuestao.php:65
ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:547

Da esse erro ai acima!